# Referencing Springer products: what name to use for the publisher?

Tags: citations, publishers

For references to Springer products, I have come across a lot of names for the publisher, (and all of those are present in my own Mendeley library):

- Springer Science+Business Media
- Springer-Verlag
- Springer

Is there a difference, or can I just go and standardize my library to one of them (preferably Springer. In my area, mathematics, there is no chance of confusion with Springer Publishing, and even less with Axel Springer SE)?

Also, is there a difference between the locations [New York|Heidelberg|Berlin|a combination of the previous] usually found along with Springer, or can I just standardize my library to always use Berlin, since that's where the headquarters are? I understand Springer has major offices in the other cities, but do different books really pertain to those different offices, and does this need to be made clear in the References?

If the answers to one of the questions is no, do you have a hint where to find the correct information? The first pages of the books that I have sometimes list all of the above options in different places. Furthermore, for example my copy of V.I. Arnold's "Mathematical Methods of Classical Mechanics, Second Edition" says "© 2010 Springer Science+Business Media, Inc." without any mentioning of "Springer-Verlag", whereas the [website](http://www.springer.com/us/book/9780387968902) says "Publisher: Springer-Verlag New York".

Comment: If I recall it correctly, the "Lecture Notes in Computer Science" Copyeditors always change the bibliography entries to "Springer-Verlag, Heidelberg". So if this is what they use themselves in their own books, this should be OK. In my own publications, I wouldn't even bother to put the "Heidelberg" there anymore. "Springer-Verlag" clears up any possible confusion with "Axel Springer".

Comment: @DCTLib I have in my hands a Springer book (in "A Series of Comprehensive Studies in Mathematics") where all of those are found in the references: "Springer, Berlin", "Springer-Verlag, Berlin", "Springer-Verlag, New York". The copyright notice on the book itself says "© Springer-Verlag Berlin Heidelberg", and the name written under the ISBN and DOI is "Springer Heidelberg New York Dordrecht London".

Comment: @DCTLib How would you find out if a book was actually published by Springer-Verlag (in my understanding a part of Springer Science+Business Media)? Also, by now I also found "Publisher: Springer Berlin Heidelberg" for a book on springer.com. Furthermore,  in a single book (incidentally published by Springer) i found "Springer-Verlag, Berlin", "Springer-Verlag, Berline[sic!], New York, Heidelberg" and "Springer-Verlag, Berlin-Heidelberg". Conclusion: 
"Springer, Berlin" it is, no one seems to care

Comment: Since you are in mathematics, my suggestion is: take your bibtex entries from Mathscinet, unmodified. So use whatever they use.

Comment: I usually write "Springer-Verlag", and I don't list any cities.  As far as I can tell, the publisher's location was important in olden times, when people might want to order a book by sending snail-mail to the publisher. Nowadays, the location seems useless.  I don't recall ever having any complaints from editors or publishers about omitting the locations.

Comment: "Springer Science+Business Media" is the parent company not only of Springer-Verlag but also of other publishers such as Birkhauser or Kluwer, so it would seem odd to use it as a synonym for Springer-Verlag (I suppose you would not use it for a Birkhauser book). Personally I just use Springer, and for the city I use what's written in the book, generally Berlin Heidelberg or New York, sometimes London.

Answer (score 8):

The suffix *"-Verlag"* basically just means "publisher" or "publishing company in German. Therefore, I would include it only if other companies in English—such as Dover Publications, for instance—also appear with the "publishing" term in their listings. If they don't, I'd eliminate the *"-Verlag"* for consistency.

As for the others, those tend to be "imprints" within the publishing house. In general, I believe these can also be omitted, particularly in "abbreviated" citation styles. In longer styles where full details are provided, you may provide this information; if the publisher doesn't want to include it, they can remove it when editing the proofs.

Comment: Thank you. I own a lot of the yellow books published by them. I never knew Verlag just mean publisher.