# Who is the publisher of the SpringerOpen journals?

Tags: publishers, springer

This question is closely related to [this one](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/58891/referencing-springer-products-what-name-to-use-for-the-publisher) and is also about the (at least for me) confusing aggregation of publishers around the term "Springer". In particular, I am asking about the journals published under the brand SpringerOpen, such as the "EURASIP Journal on Wireless Communications and Networking".

What is the name and address of the associated publisher?

At least the following terms come to my mind:

- Springer Nature
- SpringerOpen
- BioMed Central
- Springer
- Springer Verlag
- Springer Science+Business Media

Possible addresses include:

- Luxemburg
- Berlin
- Heidelberg
- London

Comment: As you can read on the "History" page at https://www.springer.com/us/about-springer/history, the company has been through several mergers, with associated name changes.  That should answer some of your questions.  Also, "Verlag" is just the German word for "publishing house".

Comment: @NateEldredge Thanks a lot for the hint! I am already aware of (some parts of) Springer's history, but the old names do not seem to be obsolete but remain as business units, so this confuses me even more...

Comment: I'm a little curious why these details of Springer's org chart should matter to an outsider.  Can you explain briefly your reason for asking this question?  What problem are you really trying to solve?

Comment: Only for citation purposes, [please see my follow up question](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/116379/61201).

Answer (score 3):

SpringerOpen is just a brand of the company Springer Nature. [You can find some info here.](https://www.springeropen.com/about) It's also the name of the website where you can access the articles. It allows them to cram the word "Springer" in more places if they brand every single one of their open access journals. It's like how McDonald's chicken nuggets aren't just nuggets, they're mcnuggets. Springer's open access journals aren't just open access, they're "SpringerOpen".

Citations of journal articles do not typically include the publisher. The journal's name is sufficient. In fact, if you go to to your journal's website, they explicitly say:

> Citing articles in EURASIP Journal on Wireless Communications and Networking
>
> [...] Article citations follow this format:
>
> Authors: Title. EURASIP J Wirel Commun Netw [year], [volume number]:[article number].

Since journals can (and do) change publishers, there is no point in listing the publisher. In fact, this could be actively harmful if the journal changes hand at some point in the future. People will wonder if they're looking at the correct thing.

If you look, you will also see that the copyright holder is "BioMed Central Ltd", which is owned by Springer Nature. So if you are really intent on listing something, I would list that. The company's HQ is in London.